# mongo $or to return a single document base don first critera

Tags: mongodb

I have the following query:

```
   db.getCollection('MyCollection').find({
    $or: [{

            "Zips": {                
                $elemMatch: { "ZipCode5": "95757" , "ZipCode4": "6237"}
            }

    }, {
        "Zips": {
                $elemMatch: { "ZipCode5": "95757" , "ZipCode4": "0000"}
            }
    }]
})
```

I have both documents on my collection, but I want only to return the document that matches the first criteria if both exist, and the 2nd if the first dosn't exist.
Currently, the above query returns both if they both exist.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just limit to first row then?..

```
   db.getCollection('MyCollection').find({
    $or: [{

            "Zips": {                
                $elemMatch: { "ZipCode5": "95757" , "ZipCode4": "6237"}
            }

    }, {
        "Zips": {
                $elemMatch: { "ZipCode5": "95757" , "ZipCode4": "0000"}
            }
    }]
}).limit(1)
```